# Is it possible to print out an IndexError from a discord bot?

Tags: discord, discord.py, index-error

I want to print out and `IndexError("List index out of range")` from my Discord bot into a channel if something is incorrectly executed. However my method, which I also used for `AttributeErrors`, does not work. Where is the mistake I made?

```py
try:
    message = await channel.fetch_message(id_)
except IndexError:
    return await ctx.send('The ID that was entered was incorrect, make sure you have entered the correct giveaway message ID.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Messageable.fetch_message` never raises `IndexError`, it raises the following:

- [`discord.Notfound`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_message#discord.NotFound) - if the message was not found
- [`discord.Forbidden`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_message#discord.Forbidden) - if you don't have the required permissions
- [`discord.HTTPException`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_message#discord.HTTPException) - when retrieving the message failed

Answering your question - you can simply except `discord.NotFound` error

```py
try:
    message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
except discord.NotFound:
    await ctx.send("The ID that was entered is incorrect, make sure you have entered the correct giveaway message ID.")
```